# How to the change default inking color in PowerPoint 2016 slideshow

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I teach classes by inking PowerPoint slideshows. With inking, I annotate and highlight slides (`CTRL-P` and `CTRL-I`, respectively) using a Wacom monitor and stylus.

The default inking color is red, but I prefer blue. Students prefer blue, too. I know how to change the inking color using the menu at the lower left corner of the slideshow (see screenshot below), but this is tedious. **Is there a way to change the default inking color to blue?**

FWIW, I use PowerPoint 2016 on Windows 10.

[image: screenshot of inking color menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pen color can be changed within the **Set Up Show** options.

Under the **Slide Show** portion of the ribbon, select **Set Up Show**

[image: Set Up Show - Change Pen Color]

Under **Show options**, change the pen color to blue.